# Web and Mobile Web: Subdomains or External CSS for propert layout?

Tags: css, mobile-website

I am designing an app that I want to run on both web and mobile web browsers. Obviously I need different layouts and views for both seeing that they have drastically-different size constraints for the UIs. I will obviously also need some kind of browser detection to figure out whether or not the request is coming from a web or mobile web client.

I have seen this solution implement is 2 ways:

- Route HTTP requests differently depending on whether the detected client is web (send to `www.example.com`) or mobile web (send to `m.example.com`); or
- Return different CSS sheets depending on whether the detected client is web (`app-styles-web.css`) or mobile web (`app-styles-mobile.css`)

My question: what are the pros/cons to each strategy and why? Subdomains seem like a bit unnecessary, seeing that you're going to have to have 2 different CSS sheets anyways, but perhaps they are becoming a "best practice" because they separate concerns? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not use css media queries to detect browser width? That would even work when users have a narrow browser screen. Have a look here: http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Answer (score 1):

A lot of the larger vendors tend to use a sub-domain because it allows the end client browser to be sure that they are redirecting to the correct version of the site. Consider today's dot-com giants - Facebook, Twitter, Yahoo, they all have their own compact mobile based sub-domains.

Consider the case that I use my smartphone to view a website - `www.example.com`. There's some code that detects my user-agent and redirects me to its mobile web equivalent sub-domain `m.example.com`. Tomorrow, I view the same website on a bespoke browser on another hand-set. This browser conceals the meta-data so that the user agent received at the code is not that of a smartphone. It'll now load the web-based version of the same website risking the fact that web-pages/CSS/JavaScript will render incorrectly. Fortunately, I know that there's a mobile web sub-domain of the same site so I'll hit my address bar to point to the correct sub-domain.

Finally, there are strong SEO implications, a sub-domain is treated as a completely different website so you may put yourself at a disadvantage if you'd just load a different view.

Few months back I too faced a similar conundrum. But I evaluated and thought of on all the above points that I mentioned and today I ended up having lots of happy customers :-)
If you'd like to play it safe, use the sub-domain approach.